# Order of execution between static blocks and init functions

Tags: java, static-methods, static-initializer

What is the defined execution order between static blocks and static initialization functions? Is it their order in the class definition?

For example:

```
public class Test {

    static  {System.out.println("1");   }

    static int x = getX();  static int getX() { System.out.println("2"); return 5; }

    static { System.out.println("3"); }
}
```

Prints 1,2,3 on my system. Is this guaranteed by Java?
I've seen similar questions, but not one that contained an answer for this.

Comment: Have a look at the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2).: "Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, _in textual order_, as though they were a single block." - Note, however, that it's easy to write code that confuses the developer on the order of execution so you should be _very_ careful when relying on such things.

Comment: `static` is 99.999% sequential.